# How to apply filter on results from List all Azure Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-rest-api

I want to apply a filter on all the result return via NSG to only name or a specific name is this possible ?

```
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups?`$filter=name eq 'xxx-nsg'&api-version=2020-07-01"
```

This returns all the result without a filter. I would like to use **equals/contains** to filter

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to make use of [`List Resources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) API. That allows you to specify `$filter` criteria with support for `contains` query.

For example, I tried to list the storage accounts in my Azure Subscription that contained `v2` in it. This is how my request URL looks like:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resources?api-version=2020-06-01&$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' and substringof('v2', name)
```

For you, I guess the same URL would be something like:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resources?api-version=2020-06-01&$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups' and substringof('xxx', name)
```